# How to configure extraQueryParameters for redirect request in MSAL.js

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, msal-react

My react app uses MSAL (@azure/msal-browser) for user authentication, so I configure MSAL instance in my index.tsx using configuration object:

```
const config = {
  clientId: "myAppId",
  msalConfig: {
    auth: {
      authority: "signUpSignInCustomPolicyURI",
      clientId: "myAppId",
      knownAuthorities: ["myB2CTenant.b2clogin.com"],
      redirectUri: "/"
    },
    cache: {<cacheconfig>}
  },
  loginScopes: ['openid', 'offline_access'],
  authorities: {
    signUpSignIn: "signUpSignInCustomPolicyURI",
    forgotPassword: "forgotPasswordCustomPolicyURI",
  }
}
msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(config);
```

Then I wrap my app component in MsalProvider component:

```
<MsalProvider instance={msalInstance}>
  <App/>
</MsalProvider>
```

and use `<MsalAuthenticationTemplate>` in protected components so users are prompted to login automatically.

On the other hand, we have an ability to add extra parameters to RequestRedirect like this:

```
const { instance } = useMsal();
const loginRedirectRequest = {
  scopes: <myLoginScopes>,
  extraQueryParameters: {
    locale: "localeId",
    theme: "themeId"
  }
};
instance.loginRedirect(loginRedirectRequest);
```

My question is how to configure MSAL instance so it would apply `extraQueryParameters` every time it redirects users automatically?

Answer (score 1):

I asked the same question recently in issues and was kindly responded to by one of the contributors.

He suggested to use the standard OAuth `state` property to pass and receive custom values (not `extraQueryParameters` which only go to the login page), and pointed me at this article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-js-pass-custom-state-authentication-request

Answer (score 0):

Add it into the MSAL config object to start with.

```
const config = {
  clientId: "myAppId",
  msalConfig: {
    auth: {
      authority: "signUpSignInCustomPolicyURI",
      clientId: "myAppId",
      knownAuthorities: ["myB2CTenant.b2clogin.com"],
      redirectUri: "/"
    },
    cache: {<cacheconfig>}
  },
  loginScopes: ['openid', 'offline_access'],
  authorities: {
    signUpSignIn: "signUpSignInCustomPolicyURI",
    forgotPassword: "forgotPasswordCustomPolicyURI",
  },
  extraQueryParameters: {
    locale: "localeId",
    theme: "themeId"
  }
}
msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(config);
```

Comment: Just like this? Could not find anything about this here: https://azuread.github.io/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/ref/modules/_azure_msal_browser.html#configuration
Nevertheless, I tried with no luck. At the same time, I realized I need these parameters to be dynamic and depend on the current context, so I can't just configure it once and for all at the start when MSAL instance is created.
Does it mean I'm ending up with <CustomAuthenticationTemplate>?

Comment: If it’s dynamic, then pass the loginRedirectRequest object as you already noted.

Comment: The question is how to pass it to <MsalAuthenticationTemplate> if it's possible at all.